# Simular tecla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Tengo un juego en JS que requiere de teclado. Dos teclas. El cambio de las teclas es bastante compliado. Quiero añadir un botón que simule la pulsación de esa tecla.

```
<button onclick="presskey('32')">A</button>


function pressKey(i)
  {var keyboardEvent = i;
   document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
      }
```

Algo así podría ser la lógica

Comment: No termina de quedar clara la pregunta. Intenta añadir una descripción más detallada del problema y de por qué el es complicado. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que completes el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Quizá lo estás viendo desde un punto de vista equivocado: pulsar una tecla realiza una acción, el botón debe realizar la misma acción: simplemente haz que en ambos casos se llame a la función que realiza la acción

Comment: Este es el juego: http://www.psytoolkit.org/experiment-library/experiment_wcst.html

Comment: No encuentro la función que es activada por cada tecla. ya que esta depende del paso en el que esté.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un nuevo [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent). Inicializarlo y darle la propiedad de la tecla que quieres simular.

La documentación de KeyboardEvent nunca me ha quedado muy clara. Algunos recomiendan usar `key` y otros usar `which`. Ahora hice la prueba y el siguiente ejemplo no envía el charcode 32, pero sí simula presionar Space.

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {which:32,  key:' ', code:'Space',keyCode:32, charCode:32});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Aparentemente esto es un comportamiento propio de Chrome porque en Firefox sí funciona. En Chrome lo siguiente me resultó (tomado de un ejemplo en [jsbin](http://output.jsbin.com/awenaq/3))

```
var eventObj = document.createEventObject ?
    document.createEventObject() : document.createEvent("Events");

if(eventObj.initEvent){
  eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
}

eventObj.keyCode = 32;
eventObj.which = 32;
eventObj.key=' ';
eventObj.code='Space';
document.dispatchEvent ? document.dispatchEvent(eventObj) : document.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);
```