# Simular una tecla pulsada en el código JS del dinosaurio de Chrome

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando conectar la conexión de un botón de una Beagle Bone Black con el salto del dinosaurio del juego de chrome. He encontrado el JS y ya tengo hecha la conexión entre la BBB y el PC, de tal forma que tengo una variable en JS que cambia de 0 a 1 cuando se presiona el botón, y quiero linkarla con el salto del dinosaurio.

- He visto que la una manera es simular que se presiona la tecla cuando la variable pasa de 0 a 1, pero no se cómo implementarlo ni en qué lugar del código introducirlo.
- Tampoco sé si hay una manera más fácil de hacerlo, como simplemente llamar a la función que triggea el salto cuando esta variable cambia.

No cabe el código, pero está disponible en este [link](https://codepen.io/MysticReborn/pen/rygqao?editors=1010).

Primero se define una función que se llama Runner, con todos los parámetros del dinosaurio.

```
function Runner(outerContainerId, opt_config){...
```

En esta parte asigna los keycodes para las flechas, entiendo que desde aquí no se puede solucionar el problema, a no ser que se pudiera crear un "keycode" que cambiara con una variable...

```
Runner.keycodes = {
    JUMP: {'69': 1, '32': 1}, // Up, spacebar
    DUCK: {'40': 1}, // Down
    RESTART: {'13': 1} // Enter
    };
```

Aquí la función de EventHandler:

```
handleEvent: function(e) {
    return (function(evtType, events) {
    switch (evtType) {
    case events.KEYDOWN:
    case events.TOUCHSTART:
    case events.MOUSEDOWN:
    this.onKeyDown(e);
    break;
    case events.KEYUP:
    case events.TOUCHEND:
    case events.MOUSEUP:
    this.onKeyUp(e);
    break;
...
```

Se pone a escuchar los eventos de Keydown y KeyUp

```
document.addEventListener(Runner.events.KEYDOWN, this);
document.addEventListener(Runner.events.KEYUP, this);
```

Aquí el proceso de Keydown

```
 onKeyDown: function(e) {
    if (e.target != this.detailsButton) {
    if (!this.crashed && (Runner.keycodes.JUMP[String(e.keyCode)] ||
    e.type == Runner.events.TOUCHSTART)) {
    if (!this.activated) {
    this.loadSounds();
    this.activated = true;
    }
    if (!this.tRex.jumping) {
    this.playSound(this.soundFx.BUTTON_PRESS);
    this.tRex.startJump();
    }
    }
    if (this.crashed && e.type == Runner.events.TOUCHSTART &&
    e.currentTarget == this.containerEl) {
    this.restart();
    }
    }
    // Speed drop, activated only when jump key is not pressed.
    if (Runner.keycodes.DUCK[e.keyCode] && this.tRex.jumping) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.tRex.setSpeedDrop();
    }
    }
```

Y aquí el de Keyup

```
onKeyUp: function(e) {
    var keyCode = String(e.keyCode);
    var isjumpKey = Runner.keycodes.JUMP[keyCode] ||
    e.type == Runner.events.TOUCHEND ||
    e.type == Runner.events.MOUSEDOWN;
    if (this.isRunning() && isjumpKey) {
    this.tRex.endJump();
    } else if (Runner.keycodes.DUCK[keyCode]) {
    this.tRex.speedDrop = false;
    } else if (this.crashed) {
    // Check that enough time has elapsed before allowing jump key to restart.
    var deltaTime = getTimeStamp() - this.time;
    if (Runner.keycodes.RESTART[keyCode] ||
    (e.type == Runner.events.MOUSEUP && e.target == this.canvas) ||
    (deltaTime >= this.config.GAMEOVER_CLEAR_TIME &&
    Runner.keycodes.JUMP[keyCode])) {
    this.restart();
    }
    } else if (this.paused && isjumpKey) {
    this.play();
    }
    },
```

Aquí está la función que hace que salte el dinosaurio:

```
startJump: function() {
    if (!this.jumping) {
    this.update(0, Trex.status.JUMPING);
    this.jumpVelocity = this.config.INIITAL_JUMP_VELOCITY;
    this.jumping = true;
    this.reachedMinHeight = false;
    this.speedDrop = false;
    }
    },
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque no te quepa todo el código, ¿podrías pegar en modo texto las partes más relevantes relacionadas con la pregunta?. Y por cierto, me encanta este proyecto del dinosaurio ;D

Comment: Buenas Órdago! he intentado meter lo más importante, a ver si se puede hacer algo. La verdad que si funciona está muy chulo jeje

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simular tecla JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112226/simular-tecla-javascript)

Comment: He estado probando pero no lo consigo, si pudieras aportar algún ejemplo con el código en cuestión me lo facilitaría muchísimo.

Comment: En inglés, pero el ejemplo es muy sencillo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299177/2412893

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funciona!